# undefined and null

Tags: javascript

```
undefined === null => false
undefined == null => true
```

1. I have thought about the reason of `undefined == null` and found out only one case:

   ```
   if(document.getElementById() == null) ....
   ```

   Is there any other reason to make (`undefined === null) == false` ?
2. Is there any other examples of use `===` - operation in javascript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any other reason to make (undefined === null) == false ?

They are not equal so the [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.6) considers them to be false.

> Is there any other examples of use === - operation in javascript?

The `===` gives the most predictable result. I only use `==` when I have a specific purpose for type coercion. (See [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3).)

Comment: @Raynos: Yeah, I waited a few extra seconds so you could catch up. ;o)

Answer (score 4):

`null` and `undefined` are two different concepts. `undefined` is the lack of value (if you define a variable with var without initializing it, it doesn't contain `null`, but `undefined`), while with `null` the variable exists and is initialized with the value `null`, which is a special type of value.

JavaScript equality operator is broken though, Crockford found out that it lacks transitivity and for this reason suggests to use always the strict equality (===). Consider this table published in Javascript the good parts:

```
'' == '0'          // false
0 == ''            // true
0 == '0'           // true

false == 'false'   // false
false == '0'       // true

false == undefined // false
false == null      // false
null == undefined  // true
```

Comment: *"undefined is the lack of value (probably the variable doesn't exist),"* That's not quite right. With `undefined`, the variable does exist, but it has been assigned (or reassigned) its default value `undefined`. If you try to compare to a variable that doesn't exist, you get a `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 3):

`===` is strict equal.

Undefined and null are not the same thing.

`==` uses type coercion.

`null` and `undefined` coerce to each other.

Answer (score 3):

`Type coercion` (using the == operator) can lead to undesired or unexpected results. After following all the talks I could find of Douglas Crockford on the net (mostly Yahoo video) I got used to using `===` all te time. Given my default usage of the strict equal operator I would be more interested in type coercion javascript use cases ;~) nowadays.