# Javascript: Explain If Type(x) is Undefined, return true. If Type(x) is Null, return true

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

> 11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm
>
> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed  as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. **If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.**
> 3. **If Type(x) is Null, return true.**
> 4. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    1. If x is NaN, return false.
>    2. If y is NaN, return false.
>    3. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    4. If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
>    5. If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
>    6. Return false.
> 5. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and  same characters in
>      corresponding positions); otherwise, return false.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false; otherwise, return false.
> 7. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return  false. NOTE This algorithm differs from the SameValue Algorithm (9.12)
>      in its treatment of signed zeroes and NaNs

What does the bolded section mean? How do you write out some JavaScript to confirm it?
I tried `alert(typeof(undefined) === 'x');` but it gives me `false`.

Comment: Can you fill the blahs in order to give us more context without having to download an external PDF file?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031372/undefined-and-null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before that it says:

> where `x` and `y` are value

So first, give `x` and `y` values.

Then forget "blah", 1 is important. `x` and `y` have to be the same type to get past step 1.

Step 2 is "If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.".

There is only one value that gives the undefined type, `undefined`. Thus, the only way to test step 2 (short of assigning `undefined` to variables):

```
alert(undefined === undefined)
```

… will give true.

Step 3 works in exactly the same way. The only null value is `null`.

```
alert(null === null)
```

A manual implementation the algorithm would start like this:

```
function equalsequalsequals(x, y)
if (typeof x != typeof y) {
    return false;
} else if (typeof x == "undefined") {
    return true;
} // …
```

The typeof operator can't tell us if something is null or not, so you can't completely implement the algorithm without using `===`. Since we have `===`, however, we don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation is one of reading the spec as a formal proof, having the numbers 2 and 3 dependent on the first rule:

> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.

Since you are at step 2 and have not returned `false`, the type of X must be the same as of Y, so the condition it is checking for is:

```
(null) === (null)
```

which returns `true`. The same applies with `Undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`Type()` is an internal method, not available in your javascript code. It is *not* identical to the `typeof` operator.

`x` and `y` refer to the left and right hand operands of `===`. They are not strings `'x'` and `'y'`.

http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6