# Overloading Functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, overloading

I have been using jQuery for a year, but I still don't understand how this code works:

```
alert($('#elementID').val()); // It gets the value of element

$('#elementID').val('setting Value'); // the same function is setting value
```

some other functions of jquery also do the same like `.html()`

I want to know how this thing is achieved? How do they overload a javascript function?

Comment: It just checks to see if a value is given in the function, if not it retrieves the current value ?

Comment: @adeneo yes it is does so but how thing happens , I dont know any technique to do so with the same function

Comment: Hmm, in C++, we can use default parameters to mimic overloading, and here, optional parameters for javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no overloads in javascript, so feats like this are performed using optional parameters. JavaScript allows you to call functions without specifying parameters. For example:

```
function val(text)
{
  if (arguments != null && arguments.length > 0) {
    alert("i'm setting value here to " + text);
  } else {
    alert("i'm getting value here");
  }
}

val(); // alerts value getter
val('hi!'); // alerts value setter and the message
```

This example was written to point out [arguments collection which you get in every function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). Every function can fetch it's parameters as a collection and can accordingly perform it's logic. However, displayed example would be written differently in real world:

```
function val(text)
{
  if (typeof text === "string") {
    alert("i'm setting value here to " + text);
  } else {
    alert("i'm getting value here");
  }
}
```

Each parameter which you do not pass to a function gets "value" of `undefined` (not `null`). This lets you use the shortest logical expression. You can use any value in `if` statement. Variables which are `null` or `undefined` will simply be evaluated as `false`.

As a comment below pointed out if `text` parameter is empty string `if (text)` would return false. For that reason, for text parameters check parameters by type.

It would be beneficial for you to also [read about `null` and `undefined` differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031611/187955).

Comment: in your first code snippet var "arguments" is it a default keyWord? or where you defined it ?

Comment: Arguments is default keyword. I also provided link to Mozilla Developer Network where you can read about it.

Comment: @Rupesh: They wrote *"This example was written to point out [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) collection which you get in every function. Every function can fetch it's parameters as as collection and can accordingly perform many operations."*. There is already a link (see the blue text?) that you can follow to learn more about `arguments`.

Comment: Empty string and 0 are also evaluated as false, so in your second example you can't set value by calling `val(0)`

Comment: @RupeshPatel, here is a [link for arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Answer (score 5):

It's simply done by checking if the function was called with a parameter or not

```
function stuff(moreStuff){
   if(typeof moreStuff === "undefined"){
      return originalStuff;
   }else{
      setStuff(moreStuff);
   }
}
```

Comment: so there is no overloading concept in JS but we can do some work around, Thanks for reply :)

Comment: It is safe to write `if(moreStuff === undefined)` in this example because `moreStuff` is an argument. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603

Answer (score 3):

Very simple, just check if the variable has a value:

```
function foo(param) {
    // Method 1
    if (param != null) {
        // Parameter is defined
    } else {
        // No parameter (or null given)
    }

    // Method 2
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        // At least one argument has been defined
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the second option. But your `param != null` may not work as intended - see http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html

Comment: this doesn't work null will not match with param if called lie this foo()

Comment: @techfoobar I'm aware of that, but the check as implemented in my code above simply allows only parameters that are not `undefined` and not `null`.

Comment: @RupeshPatel Yes, it will. If you do `foo()`, `param` will be `undefined` - and `undefined == null` is true.

Comment: @Niko As per I know undefined is the type and null is an object itself

Comment: @RupeshPatel Yes, but that does not apply in this case. `typeof x;` yields "undefined" if you have never defined a variable "x" before. However, the variable that contains a function parameter ("param" in the above code) is always defined. If no value has been specified (`foo()` instead of `foo("bar")`), the value of that variable is `undefined` (that's a special value!). You can therefore access the variable without receiving a ReferenceError, what enables you to simply test for `!= null` - that way, you sort out both undefined and null values, because both are not real values.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(value)
{
     if(typeof value != 'undefined')
     {
         // calling foo(2332)
     }
     else
     {
         // foo()
     }
}
```

Comment: Your param name is `value` and you're checking against `yourvar`!

Answer (score 1):

As nearly everyone else mentioned, they did not overload the parameter, but in the first statement, there is not arguments provided for the function. In the second one though, an argument has been provided. Therefore a simple check `typeof something == "undefined"` could easily modify and set apart the different results.

This is the relevant jQuery code making up the `.val()` function (version 1.8.0):

```
val: function( value ) {
        var hooks, ret, isFunction,
            elem = this[0];

        if ( !arguments.length ) {
            if ( elem ) {
                hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

                if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" )) !== undefined ) {
                    return ret;
                }

                ret = elem.value;

                return typeof ret === "string" ?
                    // handle most common string cases
                    ret.replace(rreturn, "") :
                    // handle cases where value is null/undef or number
                    ret == null ? "" : ret;
            }

            return;
        }

        isFunction = jQuery.isFunction( value );

        return this.each(function( i ) {
            var val,
                self = jQuery(this);

            if ( this.nodeType !== 1 ) {
                return;
            }

            if ( isFunction ) {
                val = value.call( this, i, self.val() );
            } else {
                val = value;
            }

            // Treat null/undefined as ""; convert numbers to string
            if ( val == null ) {
                val = "";
            } else if ( typeof val === "number" ) {
                val += "";
            } else if ( jQuery.isArray( val ) ) {
                val = jQuery.map(val, function ( value ) {
                    return value == null ? "" : value + "";
                });
            }

            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ this.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ this.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

            // If set returns undefined, fall back to normal setting
            if ( !hooks || !("set" in hooks) || hooks.set( this, val, "value" ) === undefined ) {
                this.value = val;
            }
        });
    }
```